# replace Fragment & add Fragment in android

Tags: android, fragment

I use this code to replace fragment with another on ***android 4.0.4***

```
FragmentManager manager;
manager=getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
 Fragment1 f1=new Fragment1();
 Fragment2 f2=new Fragment2();
public void replace_one(View v)
    {
        Fragment1 f1=(Fragment1)manager.findFragmentByTag("f1");
        transaction.remove(f1);             
        transaction.replace(R.id.place,f2,"f2");
        transaction.commit();
}
```

this code works,but for ***android 4.4.2 does not work*** and for android 4.1.2 it is working

if i use this code:

```
   FragmentManager manager;
    manager=getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
     Fragment1 f1=new Fragment1();
     Fragment2 f2=new Fragment2();
    public void replace_one(View v)
        {
            Fragment1 f1=(Fragment1)manager.findFragmentByTag("f1");
            transaction.remove(f1);             
            transaction.add(R.id.place,f2,"f2");
            transaction.commit();
    }
```

this code **works for android 4.4.2**,but for android ***4.0.4 does not work*** and for android 4.1.2 it is working

What is wrong??

Comment: its there in the logcat.

Comment: What means working? What is the your expected behaviour? What is your received behaviour?

Comment: i am meaning: fragment1 hide and fragment2 show

Comment: i used import android.app.Fragment

Comment: i read this statment: If you want to make your app use fragments, and want to target devices before API 11, you must use android.support.v4.app.Fragment. However, if you're only targeting devices running API 11 or above, you can use android.app.Fragment.

Comment: i write inside fragment2 :final CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), web,im);
GridView grid=(GridView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.grid);
getActivity() wrong or true here?

Answer (score 0):

**Here's how you will add or replace a fragment:**

```
   //TO add your fragment
    SomeFragment fragment = SomeFragment.getInstance()//If you have made your fragment singleton.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(YOUR_CONTAINER_ID, YOUR FRAGMENT, YOUR_FRAGMENT_UNIQUE_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();

    //TO replace your fragment
    SomeFragment fragment = SomeFragment.getInstance()//If you have made your fragment singleton.
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(YOUR_CONTAINER_ID, YOUR FRAGMENT, YOUR_FRAGMENT_UNIQUE_TAG).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

**And import :**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Comment: I created 12 fragments but imported android.app.Fragment